# Quarkus Native Amazon SQS Extended Library

Tags: amazon-sqs, quarkus

I have a Quarkus project that has the Amazon SQS Extended Library as a dependency. I am trying to convert this into a native image but am experiencing some difficulty. It seems as though the issue comes from the fact that the SQS library uses commons-logging. So because it uses commons logging I am getting the following error: "Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryIMpl.handleThrowable(java.lang.Throwable). This error is reported at image build time because class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl is registered for linking at image build time by command line"

Not sure how to fix this problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.amazonservices/quarkus-amazon-sqs extension?

Comment: Yes but there is no support for the SQS extended library. I came across this [Quarkus Configuring Logging](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters). This seemed to address my problem.